# Set Cookie in response header

Tags: 7, cookies

I'm actually having a strange problem with one of my drupal installations. While I was trying to setup [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) for one of my sites, I ran into an issue that only the frontpage wont get cached.

After a bit of debugging, I found out that for some reason drupal always adds an session cookie to the HTTP response header (see screenshot)

[image]

This cookie is only added to the frontpage of my site, all other pages do not have it.
By adding this cookie, drupal prevents nginx to cache this site, cause I dont want users to be redirected to cached pages if they are logged in.

Someone have an idea where that cookie comes from? I checked other drupal installations,  but those don't have this cookie.

Comment: Do you have the statistics module turned on? Which version of Drupal is this?

Comment: Please keep your screenshots under 630px when posting here. You know, for readability.

Comment: Letharion, yes its on I will try to turn it off and check again.
Molot: Oh sry i dont know that, i will resize it in a min.

Comment: @Letharion: Turning of the statistics module doesnt help, this is drupal 7.32, Molot: Resized the image ;)

Comment: Statistics is the only module I know off that will deliberately force sessions on everyone (so it can do it's tracking). I don't think this is default behaviour (it was in D6 though, hence my version question), so I think you will have to narrow it down to what you installed/coded/configured to cause this on your own.

Comment: is it possible to the session be initialized by a custom module?  can you print $_SESSION to check what contains? maybe that could give you some ideas of where is the code which initialize the sessions.